# Drag value in simulation blows up and then NaN

Tags: javascript, canvas, simulation, physics, nan

I'm writing a "physics simulation" (so to speak) where using the keyboard arrows one applies forces to a sphere. In this latest iteration I added drag, like the sphere is in the air. Then, for certain values, the drag calculation starts to blow up! The number gets too big, and then Infinity and right after that NaN (cause of the Infinity / Infinity division).

You can see it happening here: http://gool.jit.su/the-drag. Open the console and start moving, left or right. In a few seconds it breaks. You can see in the console the drag value being logged until right before it becomes NaN. (we have a great force and a very small mass)

I'm really trying to understand what is happening and why it is happening, but perhaps there are already information on similar problemas that I was unable to find out or some sort of best practice to keep the number under control... Perhaps choose a value to be my MAX and test agains it every time...

Any idea, help and suggestion is very welcome. I think I am about to learn something important, but still needing a push in the right direction. :)

**UPDATE 2**: @Beta's test (sorta)

After @Beta's comment I did this test and indeed his calculations seems to show where my simulation breaks apart. (console log velocity in the x axis when the test returns true, false otherwise)

[image]

**UPDATE 1**: Some code

Most "physics" happen here:

```
update: function update(k, dt) {

    var up = k.UP,
        right = k.RIGHT,
        down = k.DOWN,
        left = k.LEFT;

    up = up && -this.output;
    right = right && this.output;
    down = down && this.output;
    left = left && -this.output;

    this.force.x = left + right;
    this.force.y = up + down;


    this.calculate_drag(this.velocity);

    if (!isNaN(this.drag.x)) {
        console.log(this.drag);
    }

    // this.net_force.x = this.force.x;
    // this.net_force.y = this.force.y;

    this.net_force.x = this.force.x + this.drag.x;
    this.net_force.y = this.force.y + this.drag.y;


    this.acceleration.x = this.net_force.x / this.mass;
    this.acceleration.y = this.net_force.y / this.mass;

    this.velocity.x += this.acceleration.x / (1000 / dt);
    this.velocity.y += this.acceleration.y / (1000 / dt);

    this.momentum.x = this.mass * this.velocity.x;
    this.momentum.y = this.mass * this.velocity.y;

    this.position.x += (this.velocity.x * global.METRE) / (1000 / dt);
    this.position.y += (this.velocity.y * global.METRE) / (1000 / dt);

    this.energy += (abs(this.net_force.x) + abs(this.net_force.y)) / (1000 / dt);

}
```

And here:

```
calculate_drag: function calculate_drag() {

    var c = 0.47,
        a = PI * this.radius * this.radius,
        rho = 1.22,

        direction = function direction(velocity) {

            if (velocity === 0) {
                return 1;
            }

            return velocity / abs(velocity);
        };

    this.drag.x = -0.5 * c * a * rho * this.velocity.x * this.velocity.x * direction(this.velocity.x);
    this.drag.y = -0.5 * c * a * rho * this.velocity.y * this.velocity.y * direction(this.velocity.y);

}
```

Both methods of gPrototype in gee.js.

Comment: I tried to read your code, but it is very confusing. You are mixing physical model with UI, you have lots of global variables and you attach some new variables to DOM elements. Can you show us just the "physics part"?

Comment: You are also using 3 JS libraries, which tweak the standard DOM behavior. E.g. what is Date.now() ?

Comment: @IvanKuckir Well, the only important part, I think, is in gee.js. The gPrototype is the object. I will update the question. Thanks.

Comment: @IvanKuckir Uh, Date.now() is.. what it is. As per MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now
What's the problem with it?

Comment: I see you are initializing some variables to NaN. What about using zero? Try to backtrack, where does NaN come from.

Comment: You assume that acceleration is constant over the interval, when in fact it will change as the velocity changes. So, neglecting applied force, if |v| is greater than (scribble, scribble) `4000 mass/(c a rho dt)` then drag will make the object *go faster*. If that's the problem I can suggest a better formula for updating velocity and position (but I can't confirm any of this in your sim so I'm making this a comment, not an answer).

Comment: @Beta I believe you are correct. Whenever I remove drag everything works. And did this crude test: `console.log(abs(this.velocity.x) > 4000 * this.mass / (c * a * rho * (dt / 1000)));`. Not sure if it's what you meant, but for certain values of mass and output the console logs true just before blowing up. For more reasonable values, when everything doesn't blow up, it remains false. So, a better formula, please! =) Can you tell me if my test was ok, or how I could implement a better test that anyone else could go there and see for yourself? Or something...

Comment: Can we assume that the applied force is in the direction of motion? (We can still get by without that assumption, but the math gets scarier.)

Comment: @Beta I believe we can, when the applied force is positive in the x axis we get motion to the right in the x axis. Is it what you're talking about? Of course, this is before drag starts. Then there will be a "net force" that can be (actually, must be...) opposite to the motion direction... But that's the idea, right? =)

Comment: @Beta "if |v| is greater than (scribble, scribble) 4000 mass/(c a rho dt) then drag will make the object go faster" <- You're right about that. May you tell me how (exactly) you found it out? (Or any good references?) I hope it will help myself to better understand what's going on and keep looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You have a cycle in increasing the values of variables. The values will grow very fast. NaN may be the result of some float overflows.

```
net_force += drag;
drag = velocity * velocity;
velocity += net_force;
```

And so your "physics" are probably incorrect.

Comment: Well, that's pretty much what I said in the question. Even before the first update: "number gets too big, and then Infinity and right after that NaN". For the most part the "physics" works fine, as per here: http://gool.jit.su/the-force (there is no drag in this one). What I wanna know is how exactly and how to deal with it. A personal suggestion or a best pratice in cases like this one.
Not sure what mean a "cycle". It's a loop, no doubt about, and there is some integration going on, but that's how the physics is supposed to work. Force turn into acceleration that goes into velocity...

Comment: Your program works as it is written. You probably want it to work differently, but nobody knows what was your intention, so we can not point out any "mistakes".

Comment: In your code, you have something like A grows faster than B, B grows faster than C, C grows faster than A. It is somehow contradicting, nothing works like this in physics.